# Цикл for не знает переменной которая инициализировалась в цикле?

Tags: php

```
$max_trans = 70;
$bw = 300;

for ($bw; $bw > 0; $bw-$f_bon) {
    if ($bw > $max_trans) {
        $f_bon = $max_trans;
    } else {
        $f_bon = $bw;
    }
    print $f_bon."-";
}
```

почему так? и как реализовать такую конструкцию?

Comment: А при чём здесь C++?

Comment: и если инициализировать переменную перед циклом?

Comment: вопрос вообще про циклы, а не про С

Comment: Циклы в разных языках существенно различаются, если что.

Comment: @user193361 Это здорово, что он про циклы, но вы оставили метку `C++`, которая прям никак не подходит к вашему вопросу.

Comment: А что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать такой чудо конструкцией? Поясните суть

Comment: на практике применяю в такой ситуации: есть количество условных денег, их нужно перевести другому пользователю, максимальный перевод ограничен, но не ограничено количество транзакций

Comment: Видимо вам нужна рекурсивная функция

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for ($bw; $bw > 0; $bw-$f_bon) {
> ```

```
for ($bw; $bw > 0; $bw-=$f_bon) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте `$f_bon` выше области видимости вашего `if`.

```
$max_trans = 70;
$bw = 300;
$f_bon = 0;

for ($bw; $bw > 0; $bw-=$f_bon) {
    if ($bw > $max_trans) {
        $f_bon = $max_trans;
    } else {
        $f_bon = $bw;
    }
    print $f_bon."-";
}
```

Comment: это не имеет значение! отнимаемое значение в любом случае инициализируется

Comment: `$bw-$f_bon` или `$bw-=$f_bon`?

Comment: вот вы правы, тут косяк! Запостите в ответах, я поставлю галочку!

Comment: @Qwertiy мб оформить ответом тогда, чтобы будущие читатели сразу увидели ответ (ну и вопрос, чтобы не висел в списке неотвеченных, правда тут еще от автора зависит, тыкнет ли он на "галочку")?

Comment: @user193361, готово.